# How to limit transform.translate inside a sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, limit

I have sphere named Pointer that can move everywhere with transform.Translate()
but i want this sphere can only move inside a half-sphere named LimitSphere, i don't know how to do it.

i already tried to use Mathf.Clamp but as you can see on this image
[image]

but when i set an inscribed square i loose too much space (yellow)
and when i set an circumscribed square there is too much space out of the circle (purple/pink)

So is there any solution to limit a movement inside sphere ?

EDIT :
That's my actual code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TranslationClavier : MonoBehaviour {

    public float vitesse_translation = 1.0f;



    void Update () {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.I))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.K))
            {
                transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime);
            }
    }

}
```

under you can see my little sphere and i want to clamp her inside the big sphere collider

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally did this

```
    // Get the new position for the object.
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("VerticalJD"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * vitesse_translation;
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + movement;

    // Calculate the distance of the new position from the center point. Keep the direction
    // the same but clamp the length to the specified radius.
    Vector3 offset = newPos - centerPt;
    transform.position = (centerPt + Vector3.ClampMagnitude(offset, radius));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. 
First you need to know the distance you are about to travel to, from the center of the sphere, so you do it in two steps. Assuming you are calling it from a transfrom that is parented to a sphere you can do :

```
Vector3 newPosition=transform.localPosition+myDetla;
if (newPosition.magnitude>sphereRadius) transform.Translate(myDelta);
```

This will only make the translation if the destination is within the sphere.
Whatever other conditions (like a half sphere constraint) you need to do - you can analyzing new newPosition. If you want to always move, but limit the magnitude of the movemnet, you can use the fact that you can split Vectors into direction and magnitude and reassemble them, for example

```
if (newPosition.magnitude>sphereRadius)  
      newPosition=newPosition.direction*sphereRadius; //will clamp to sphere
if (newPosition.y<0) newPosition.y=0;
transform.localPosition=newPosition;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i'm new on Unity and i'm not sure to understand well how to apply your code on mine

Comment: what is 'myDelta' ?

Comment: myDelta should be assigned the values depending on the keycodes ie. Vector3.left * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime, store it in a temporary variable before you translate

Comment: could you please give me an example on how to apply your code on mine

Comment: replace each transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * vitesse_translation * Time.deltaTime); with myDelta=Vector3.forward * vitesse_translation *Time.deltaTime (declare it earlier as Vector3 myDelta=Vector3.zero), paste my code afterwards

Comment: it doesn't works my movable sphere never stop even if i release my input

Comment: i found that https://answers.unity.com/questions/1309521/how-to-keep-an-object-within-a-circlesphere-radius.html
it's exactly what i want